# Getting all layers hovered over in a layer stack in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, overlapping-features, overlay

Using Leaflet with a map that has multiple layers on it, how can i get a list of all the layers hovered over, a la ArcGIS Online?

For example, suppose i have two circles A and B on a map in standard Venn-diagram position.
Then the list would contain both A and B when hovering over A intersect B, and would contain only A when hovering over A minus B.

I'm required by the GIS Stack Exchange moderator to include a code snippet of the situation, so here you go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .leaflet-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    const A = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 500
    }).addTo(map);

    const B = L.circle([51.508, -0.10], {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 500
    }).addTo(map);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

Comment: @TomazicM i don't have existing code, because i don't know how to approach the issue. I'm looking for responses that include suggested algorithms and plugins to use and not necessarily code.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike OpenLayers, which has `map.getFeaturesAtPixel` and `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` methods, Leaflet has no such methods.

The only way in Leaflet to get layer at current mouse position is to declare event processing function `layer.on('mousemove', evtProcessingFunction)`. Problem with this function is that in the case of overlapping layers it detects only the layer at the top.

Solution for this is pretty hacking method of detecting desired event also on Leaflet `overlayPane`, and the when event occurs hiding layer, and then again firing the event until no more layers are detected. The whole idea comes from here https://gist.github.com/perliedman/84ce01954a1a43252d1b917ec925b3dd.

Although the source of idea recommends this solution only for `click` event, I tried it with `mousemove` event and it worked OK.

Below is the code I tried and that works for this case:

```
var over = {};
var processing = false;

const A = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 500
}).addTo(map);
A.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  if (!processing) return;
  over.red = true;
});

const B = L.circle([51.508, -0.10], {
    color: 'blue',
    fillColor: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 500
}).addTo(map);
B.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  if (!processing) return;
  over.blue = true;
});

map.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  if (processing) return;
  processing = true;
  over = {};
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (Object.keys(over).length > 0) console.log(over);
    processing = false;      
  }, 5);
});

var overlayPane = map.getPane('overlayPane');

L.DomEvent.on(overlayPane, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    if (e._stopped) { return; }

    var target = e.target;
    var stopped;
    var removed;
    var ev = new MouseEvent(e.type, e)

    removed = {node: target, display: target.style.display};
    target.style.display = 'none';
    target = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

    if (target && target !== overlayPane) {
        stopped = !target.dispatchEvent(ev);
        if (stopped || ev._stopped) {
            L.DomEvent.stop(e);
        }
    }

    removed.node.style.display = removed.display;
});
```